# Override swipe events on overlapping element

Tags: angularjs, hammer.js

I have an angular 1.5.7 page using hammer.js 2.0.8 with [angular-hammer](https://github.com/RyanMullins/angular-hammer) library.

My `<body>` is 100% height and has swipe events on it that allow a user to page back and forth.  But within the body, I have a list of `<input>` tags which I have a different swipe event on.

The problem is the swipe on the `<body>` is always triggered, even when I swipe over the `<input>`.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-cloak hm-swiperight="prevDay(page)" hm-swipeleft="nextDay(page)">

    <h1>{{data[page].today | dateSuffix}}</h1>

    <div ng-repeat="item in data[page].items track by $index" 
        hm-swiperight="strikeOn(page, {{$index}})" 
        hm-swipeleft="strikeOff(page, {{$index}})"
        hm-press="splashOn(page, {{$index}})">
        <input 
            value="{{item.name}}"
            placeholder="Item #{{$index+1}}"
            ng-class="{strike: item.done==true}"
            ng-trim="true"
            ng-model="item.name"
            ng-change="save()"
        />
    </div>

</body>
```

How do get the swipe on the `<input>` to take precedence over the swipe on the `<body>`?

Answer (score 0):

`body` or parent is always prior to other inside elements, you can't touch input without touching the body and it's logical.

But if you ask me, i will put 2 `div` on left and right of my `body` and then i set attr `swiperight` and `swipeleft` on each of them, to solve this problem.

```
<body>
  <div class="left" hm-swipeleft="prevDay(page)"></div>
  <div class="right" hm-swiperight="prevDay(page)"></div>
  //----other elements
</body>
```

> **div** are absolute position, and when user swipe right from right of body it will work on body, also left, and when user touch inside body you input element will work.